# Why isn't my pasture working in Banished?

Tags: banished

I'm playing Banished and I have built the Pasture to get some food from cows, but after building it, it's not working.

The message I get from the bulding is: `Work disabled at this location`

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All livestock on banished needs to be bought. You will have to build a [trading post](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Trading_Post) and buy some members of the species you want to start the Pasture.

**Costs**:

- *Cattle*: 800 from random merchants, and 1000 when custom ordered.
- *Sheep*: 600 from random merchants, and 750 when custom ordered.
- *Chicken*: 400 from random merchants, and 500 when custom ordered.

Other aspect that you have to take care while building pastures is it's minimum size. All the 3 livestock have a minimum size required, and they will not reproduce if the size of your pasture is not enough.

Taking a look at the [Shinning Rock forums](http://shiningrocksoftware.com/forum/discussion/1068/pasture-wont-work-/p1), you can find information that the message `Work disabled at this location` basically means:

- Not enough workers to be assigned as herders or not workers assigned at all;
- No animals purchased to start the pasture production;
- No animal selected on that pasture;

**More reading:**

- [Livestock](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Livestock) - Banished Wiki
- [Pastire](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Pasture) - Banished Wiki

Comment: Assuming of course the OP doesn't have livestock sat about and it's not bugged.

Comment: But those details should be part of the question ;)

Comment: All true, but it also looks to small. Maybe you want to add the minimum size found here: http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Pasture

Comment: Thanks! I didnt had the trading post yet, I'll do, and tell something. And I'll take a look to to the miminum dimension, but I thoung that is "bigger" than it

Comment: @Shaeldon - His pasture does not seems to be 20 tiles or less. Should be enough. However, i agree that Shudy will have to resize it to achieve better performance :)